# Interop between C++ and C# via C++/CLI with callbacks

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

I want to use an existing C++ library in a C# app. The C++ library will have async callbacks for things like `OnConnect` and user updates so I want to reflect this in the eventual C# code. I would appreciate thoughts on the following implementation particularly in the area of memory leaks in the CLI part.

To begin, I have a simple C++ class:

```
#include <string>

class CppClass
{
public:

    typedef void(*Callback)(int);

    CppClass(){};
    ~CppClass(){};

    void Connect(std::string conn_info)
    {
        OnConnect();
    };

    void OnConnect()
    {
        m_callback(42);
    };

    void SetOnCallback(Callback callback)
    {
        m_callback = callback;
    };

private:
    Callback m_callback;
};
```

To communicate with this, I have a C++/CLI wrapper:

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Runtime::InteropServices;

namespace CliCpp {

    public delegate void OnConnectDelegate(int);

    public ref class WrapperClass
    {
    public: 

        // C# callback delegates
        CliCpp::OnConnectDelegate^ OnConnectHandler;

        // Ctor / dtor
        WrapperClass()
        {
            m_native = new CppClass();

            // Set OnConnect callback
            CliCpp::OnConnectDelegate^ managed_on_connect = gcnew CliCpp::OnConnectDelegate(this, &WrapperClass::OnConnect);
            IntPtr stub_ptr = Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate(managed_on_connect);
            CppClass::Callback fptr = static_cast<CppClass::Callback>(stub_ptr.ToPointer());
            m_native->SetOnCallback(fptr);
            GC::KeepAlive(managed_on_connect);
        };

        ~WrapperClass()
        {
            this->!WrapperClass();
        };

        !WrapperClass()
        {
            if (m_native != nullptr)
                delete m_native;
        };

        // Methods
        void Connect(String^ conn_info)
        {
            m_native->Connect(msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(conn_info));
        };

        // Event handler from C++ code
        void OnConnect(int i)
        {
            // Call C# code:
            OnConnectHandler(i);
        };      

    private:
        CppClass* m_native;     
    };
}
```

And finally, I have some C# calling code:

```
using CliCpp;

namespace Caller
{
    class Program
    {   
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (WrapperClass cls = new WrapperClass())
            {
                // Set up the C# callback
                cls.on_connect_handler = OnConnect;
                cls.Connect("Hello");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        // Callback Function
        static void OnConnect(int i)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("C# handler called!");
        }

    }
}
```

So, what I would like an opinion on is:

1. Is this implementation of callbacks good practice?
2. In the C++/CLI constructor where I set up the callback, am I using `gcnew` and 'GC::KeepAlive(x)' correctly so as not to leak (do I need a corresponding `delete` etc.)?

Any input appreciated!

Comment: Mixing three different languages. What can go wrong :-)

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to implement the non-async methods on the wrapper, I don't know much about callbacks and this stuff though.

Comment: As far as I can see, this is how interop between C++ and .Net is encouraged.I don't think sync calls should make any difference since calls will originate either side of the CLI bridge in any case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure about the callbacks but you are using the destructor/finalizer in a way that might cause problems.

> ```
>    ~WrapperClass()
>     {
>         this->!WrapperClass();
>     };
>
>     !WrapperClass()
>     {
>         if (m_native != nullptr)
>             delete m_native;
>     };
> ```

If you are doing this then the descructor should call `GC.SuppressFinalize(this);` because the finalizer has already been called.

Then in your finalizer you should set the `m_native = nullptr;` because if the GC calls it again later it will crash as the object has been deleted but it's still pointing to it.

```
    !WrapperClass()
    {
        if (m_native != nullptr)
        {
            delete m_native;
            m_native = nullptr;
        }
    }
```

As to the `m_native` I'd call it `_nativePtr`.

Comment: Would it make sense to just have a Destructor and leave out the finalizer?

Comment: @PatMustard You need both. The finalizer should clean-up unmanaged objects and the descructor managed ones but it can call the finalizer. [The need for C++/CLI finalize destructor](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24697358/235671)

Comment: Understood - thx!